# Не могу загрузить документ, используя AngleSharp в c#

Tags: c#, anglesharp

я хочу разобрать страницу https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/pfe/price-target, как пишут умные люди, нужно использовать AngleSharp. В простом примере с Гита подставляю свою ссылку вместо wiki... и в отладке вижу, что документ приходит пустой, ни body, ни дочерних узлов. Пробую демо пример библиотеки, выложенный на Гите, смотрю разные адреса, они нормально парсятся, но пытаюсь разобрать https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/pfe/price-target и процесс виснет на Loading, авторизации на сайте нет. Понятно, что есть какая-то особенность, которую я не вижу. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Проблема в JavaScript. При открытии данной ссылки сначала грузится небольшой html файл со скриптами, а уже скрипты отрабатывают и загружают всё остальное. Если просто грузить страницу без выполнения скриптов, то и получишь ты исходный html. Одним словом, тебе нужно или движок, который бы скрипты выполнил, или разобраться, что и куда эти скрипты отправляют, если API у сайта своего нет. AngleSharp - хз, может ли скрипты отрабатывать (судя по сайту вроде может), но лучше полноценным движком воспользоваться, тот же CefSharp.

Comment: Да, спасибо, CefSharp расковыревает страничку, но правда сайт теперь говорит, что я бот, блин, а я и правда бот, буду искать как с этим бороться.